# Why doesn't this require_once statement find the file? (PHP)

Tags: php

I not sure what's going on..maybe I missed something simple.

In my connectvars.php file, I connect to the database using the variables in my config.php folder. 
Here's the hierarchy:

```
admin(folder)
   config.php
includes(folder)
   connectvars.php
index.php
```

I want to get information from config.php to use in connectvars.php, so I use: 
require_once("../admin/config.php");
But everytime I do this I get `Warning: require_once(../admin/config.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/a8879415/public_html/includes/connectvars.php  on line 2`

BUT when I type: `require_once("admin/config.php");`, it works.

I thought I had to go up a level, then go down to admin, then get config.php. So how come I just need to go into the admin folder then get config.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running `includes/connectvars.php` directly or is it included by other file?

I think you are running `index.php` and every files are included relatively to it's path.

If you want to use relative path to other files, it can be done like that:

```
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/../admin/config.php' );
```

Comment: index.php is just in my public_html directory(the first level). O that's probably why. But why is everything running relative to the index.php? Is that default?

Answer (score 0):

They run in the context of the main script, so file references should originate from the main script's directory.